# How to create multiple user models with choices?

Tags: django-models, multiple-users

I have different types of users and have created models for each user type.signup is different for everyone.. now i want to select models at signup page according to user choices or type. for example if someone selects student then a signup page with different form fields should appear.like that i have to do for each user type.is it possible to go by the choice option with if else method inside a class and choosing the different user models according to choices??

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether your user classes share a common base class, but I think that would be essential.  The documentation has a lot of information about [using a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).  But, I recommend reading [this post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html), and going with Option 2: Using One-To-One Link With a User Model (Profile)

> **What is a One-To-One Link?** It is a regular Django model that’s gonna
>   have it’s own database table and will hold a One-To-One relationship
>   with the existing User Model through a OneToOneField.
>
> **When should I use a One-To-One Link?** You should use a One-To-One Link
>   when you need to store extra information about the existing User Model
>   that’s not related to the authentication process. We usually call it a
>   User Profile.

Comment: what i need is to select a class based on type of user.like if selected  choice is student then student class should appear.how to implement this inside our models.py??

Comment: It's hard to be sure without knowing all the details, but I think you are probably best to stick with a very simple User class that is used by Django Auth, then for your specific functionality create a Student class with a foreign key or one-to-one relationship to User.

Comment: How about creating an app for every user type and creating user models over there??because i will have different functionalities for each user type...